# Parameter productID has no default value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When ever I'm clicking a button in order to save to an Access database, I keep on getting an error:

> Parameter has no default value

Although the values are being saved in the database.

I already tried to set a default value from Access but I still get the same exception.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    Dim constring As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\PU-IMO\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\InventoryMS\InventoryMS\Real.accdb")

    Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)
      Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SalesInvoice([productID], [productnum], [productname], [productprice])  VALUES(productID, productnum, productname, productprice)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", row.Cells("productID").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productnum", row.Cells("productnum").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", row.Cells("productname").Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productprice", row.Cells("productprice").Value)

        con.Open()

        Me.DataGridView1.ClearSelection()

        Me.DataGridView1.SelectAll()

        Me.DataGridView1.Rows(Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1).Selected = False

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()
      End Using
    End Using
  Next

  MessageBox.Show("Records inserted")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have the "Allow user to add rows" set to true on the DataGridView? If so, you need to ensure that you are not trying to write that blank row.

Comment: Don't use a loop to save data from a `DataGridView`. Create a `DataTable` with the appropriate schema and bind it to the grid. You can then save all the changes in that `DataTable` to the database with a single call to `Update` on a data adapter.

Comment: The issue is that i creating an invoice form so i need a loop to add new rows everytime i fill the previous row so as to save to access...@jmcilhinney

Comment: how is it possible to exclude the last blank row and save all the previous rows i have been trying several solutions still giving the error parameter doesnt have default value...@CharlesMay

Answer (score 0):

Your insert command should be: -

```
"INSERT INTO SalesInvoice([productID], [productnum], [productname], [productprice])  
VALUES(@productID, @productnum, @productname, @productprice)"
```

use @ with value parameters

Comment: That dosn't matter in OLEDB, parameters are placeholders, the OP could have used `?` and `ColumnName` and gotten the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that got out of my head was that i did tried to save to the database an empty row so it show the above error it is now solved by a simple code and by the help of  @Charles May comment then the code is as follows:

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim constring As String = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\Users\PU-IMO\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\InventoryMS\InventoryMS\Real.accdb")
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(constring)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO SalesInvoice([productID], [productnum], [productname], [productprice]) VALUES(@productID, @productnum, @productname, @productprice)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", row.Cells("productID").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productnum", row.Cells("productnum").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", row.Cells("productname").Value)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productprice", row.Cells("productprice").Value)


                DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False

                con.Open()

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
    MessageBox.Show("Records inserted")


End Sub
```